# fail2ban не банит

Tags: linux, ubuntu, администрирование, vps

Сделал новое правило в jail.local

> [site-auth]
>   enabled  = true
>   port     = http,https
>   filter   = site-auth
>   logpath  = /home/user/web/exemple.com/public_html/runtime/login.log
>   bantime  = 3600
>   maxretry = 3

Сам фильтр выглядит вот так

> [Definition]
>   failregex = `^<HOST>`
>   ignoreregex =

Фаил логов вот такого вида

> 95.153.134.247 - - [12/Oct/2017:22:49:44]
>   109.87.5.147 - - [12/Oct/2017:22:50:00]
>   95.153.134.247 - - [12/Oct/2017:22:50:00]
>   109.87.5.147 - - [12/Oct/2017:22:50:09]
>   95.153.134.247 - - [12/Oct/2017:22:51:19]
>   95.153.134.247 - - [12/Oct/2017:22:51:28]

Правила в ipTables создаются и туда заносится ip адрес из лога, для теста попробовал забанить себя, после того как IP был внесен в список

> REJECT     all  --  46.211.3.17          0.0.0.0/0       reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Я по прежнему могу заходить на сайт, почему так происходит?
Буду очень благодарен за оказанную помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Недостаточно данных.

Либо выше вызова цепочки fail2ban есть правило, пропускающее пакеты;
Либо вы заходите на сайт с другого IP.

Для исключения первого случая используйте iptables -L -v -n
Для исключения второго — tcpdump